# Extracting text from PDF files by defining a certain number of characters in R

Tags: r, pdf

I want to collect some specific text of more than 200 PDF files, so I need something kinda "automatic" to help me.

All PDFs have almost the same structure (but not enough for me to do what I want). The text that I need comes after "Palavras" in every PDF file but not every PDF has only what I want following that.

The code I'm using now (with help from pdftools) collects the content between "Palavras" and "ABSTRACT":

```
lapply(x, function(x){
   list_output <- pdftools::pdf_text(x)
   text_output <- gsub('(\\s)+', ' ', paste(unlist(list_output), collapse=" "))
   trimws(regmatches(text_output, gregexpr("(?<=Palavras).*?(?=ABSTRACT)", text_output, perl=TRUE))[[1]][1])
})
```

But as I said, not every PDF has the same structure so it doesn't work for a lot of the files.

I think that the only thing that would work for me is to grab some certain characters after "Palavras", like a code that would extract everything that comes after "Palavras" ultil 200 or 300 characters. The problem is that I have no idea how to do that.

Any suggestions? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this question about extracting from pdf files or ... is `pdf_text` working fine and you just need help with regex and output management?

Comment: `substr(trimws(regmatches(text_output, gregexpr("(?<=Palavras).*?(?=ABSTRACT)", text_output, perl=TRUE))[[1]][1]), 1, 300)`? (The only change is enveloping with `substr(..., 1, 300)`.)

Comment: actually, i need a code that i could take the second part of the interval out because not all of them have two things in common that i could use as a interval

Comment: I think you're going to need to give textual examples that demonstrate "normal" text and "abnormal" text. Since pdf extraction is not a problem, I suggest you remove all pdf-related stuff and just focus on text manipulation.

Comment: there isn't a "normal" text and "abnormal" text. the thing is: the content on the pdf files isn't quite the same except for the "palavras" thing. so, with that, i can't set the final of the interval.
 they all have the "palavras". it comes before the text that I want to collect. so the thing that I'm looking for is like a code that would grab like 200 or 300 characteres after "palavras", without the need of an exact word to end the interval.

Comment: If the first `substr(...)` does not find anything, can't you repeat it but with a pattern of `"(?<=Palavras).*"`?